# In the reference implementation of the JAX-RS Whiteboard for OSGi, what calls createWhiteboard(..)?

Tags: osgi, aries, whiteboard

The reference implementation of OSGi's JAX-RS Whiteboard is called [Aries JAX-RS Whiteboard](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard).

My question is, how and when does the factory method for the `Whiteboard.class` get called?

```
public static Whiteboard createWhiteboard(
    Dictionary<String, ?> configuration) {

    return new Whiteboard(configuration);
}
```

Like, for example, if I drop the jar into an Apache Felix instance?

I searched the whole project for the `createWhiteboard` symbol, but I did not find anything calling it. I know it is OSGi Runtime that does this, but how, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I answered my own question.

The `Whiteboard.class` is called by a separate "activator" class that implements the standardized OSGi callback interface, `BundleActivator`: `CxfJaxrsBundleActivator` at [line 76](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/9f7d741c5293898527fa25abdbd062beccfe5148/jax-rs.whiteboard/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jax/rs/whiteboard/activator/CxfJaxrsBundleActivator.java#L76). This is analogous to the [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) of a program. Then, at [line 105](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/9f7d741c5293898527fa25abdbd062beccfe5148/jax-rs.whiteboard/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jax/rs/whiteboard/activator/CxfJaxrsBundleActivator.java#L105), the `runWhiteboard` method is called, which abstracts away the call to `createWhiteboard` use a method that is perhaps way more complicated than it should be starting at [line 198](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/9f7d741c5293898527fa25abdbd062beccfe5148/jax-rs.whiteboard/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jax/rs/whiteboard/activator/CxfJaxrsBundleActivator.java#L198).

The main calls in the stack in bottom-up order would be:

```
createWhiteboard(configuration)
runWhiteboard(bundleContext, configuration)
start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception
```